# How to aggregate information from a data-set to produce a result table

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a data-set in csv format:

```
Date    | Payment Method | Amount ($)

01-08-19  Cash             10.00
01-08-19  Cash             5.00
01-08-19  Credit           13.00
01-08-19  Credit           6.00
02-08-19  Cash             2.00
02-08-19  Credit           18.00
02-08-19  Credit           24.00
```

And I want to use pandas to add all the cash and credit purchases for each day:

```
Date    | Payment Method | Amount ($)

01-08-19  Cash             15.00
01-08-19  Credit           19.00
02-08-19  Cash             2.00
02-08-19  Credit           42.00
```

and turn it into a table like so:

```
Payment Method | Number of days that total payments exceeded $10

Cash             1
Credit           2
```

How would I go about doing this without using any loops?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve ?

```
df1=df.groupby(['Day','Payment'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()

df1
Out[28]: 
         Day Payment  Amount
0  1/08/2019    Cash      15
1  1/08/2019  Credit      19
2  2/08/2019    Cash       2
3  2/08/2019  Credit      42

df1['days Pay exceeded $10']=np.where(df1['Amount']>10,1,0)

df1
Out[30]: 
         Day Payment  Amount  days Pay exceeded $10
0  1/08/2019    Cash      15                      1
1  1/08/2019  Credit      19                      1
2  2/08/2019    Cash       2                      0
3  2/08/2019  Credit      42                      1

df1.groupby(['Payment'])['days Pay exceeded $10'].sum().reset_index()
Out[31]: 
  Payment  days Pay exceeded $10
0    Cash                      1
1  Credit                      2
```